# How do I eliminate the unexpected spacing in IE6?

Tags: css, xhtml, internet-explorer-6

First... In IE6, on the right side, there are 10 photos. In IE7, IE8, Firefox, and Chrome, it appears correctly. But in IE6, the last two photos are separated from the rest by a giant block of space of about 60px.

Any ideas where this is coming from, how to get rid of it?

Been spending last 4 hours playing with these, can't figure it out.

Much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: @cambraca - As much as I agree with you, it's not always an option.

Comment: @cambraca - Oh, come on. Don't be all defeatist.  Eliminating IE6 is always a good option.

Comment: you may try something like [this](http://www.rohanjain.in/ie/) for ie users :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to alter the width of .right class to be >=371px vs. 368? This worked for me.

Comment: This seems to be the solution. Any idea why those 3 pixels make a difference in IE6?

Comment: Glad it helped. I suspect there is possibly some IE bug related to the box model in this particular markup (even though you set the correct DTD declaration).. well, it's all about IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Add an overflow declaration to your `#body .right .photo` class:

```
{
    background:url("../images/bg-photo-trans.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    height:141px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:184px;
}
```

Comment: In this instance, adding 'overflow:hidden' doesn't seem to make any difference.